# What do you call someone who has gotten a mental disorder

Tags: single-word-requests

Michael has (blank) schizophrenia.

Comment: You'd just say, "Michael has schizophrenia."  You could also say, "Michael is schizophrenic."  Some might say, "Michael is *a* schizophrenic," but calling someone who's schizophrenic "a schizophrenic" is rude.

Comment: You use the same rules you would for any medical condition. You may contract it through a head injury, you may be born with it (even if it doesn't express itself for decades, such as schizophrenia), or you may cause it through some actions on your own part.

Comment: I don't know it's the same rules as any medical condition, like I don't see someone saying, "Michael has come down with schizophrenia," but you're right , it wouldn't technically be wrong.  I think more commonly, people would say, "Michael has *developed* schizophrenia," which does fit with what you're saying. @jimm101

Comment: “Has been diagnosed with” avoids the cause/origin question.

Comment: It depends on context, but you will need to tread carefully when discussing mental issues.  In a casual conversation, "Michael has schizophrenia" would be sufficient.  In a therapy context, "Michael has been diagnosed with schizophrenia" is better; it avoids the trap of identifying Michael with his condition, something that is very much frowned upon in social work.

Comment: I think this is the same as a medical condition? You don't come down with schizophrenia, but you also don't come down with a heart attack. There are a range of words to describe the genesis of the condition.

Comment: *Got*, not *gotten*. That works.